# Why does comparing each of C# Dictionary Key/Value pair gives different result, than comparing Dictionary Keys and Values done at once?

Tags: c#, .net, string, dictionary, equals

I've currently had to put some data in dictionary, to check whether some of the actual data, match the expected one for some of my tests.

For the task I've created a Dictionary that looked somehow like that:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {a, a},
    {b, b},
    {c, c}
};
```

1. The first that I've tried was to compare the Dictionary Values and Keys in conditional statement like shown below and I was kinda suprised with the false result of this conditional statement:

   ```
   if(dict.Keys.Equals(dict.Values)) {
       ///// received false as a result here //////
   }
   ```
2. When I then tried the next approach which was to iterate through all of dictionary items and to compare each of their Value Key pairs, it suddenly resulted in giving me the expected (true) result for all items of Dictionary:

   ```
   foreach (var item in dict) {

       if (item.Key.Equals(item.Value))
       {
           ///// received true as a result /////
       }
       else { other code here }
   }
   ```

Why did I get the false result for the first approach described?

Comment: Not sure but I think It's because the euquals check for IEnumerable<T> does not check for equality of members but the IEnumerable<T> itself...

Comment: Collections usually doesn't implement equality checks against other collections. You could use the SequenceEquals extension method to compare the elements, but this is such an edgecase that it's more for demopurposes (why would you ever have a dictionary that guarantees that keys equal values?)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Well I needed a quick way to check if some present UI web element's text (Key) which was validation message being displayed, matches the expected one to appear (value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expect them both to be an `ICollection` if you look into the [docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.system-collections-idictionary-keys?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Have a look in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) of the dictionary class. 
The `Keys` and `Values` Properties are implemented using different collection-types.

```
    // Line 135
    public KeyCollection Keys {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<KeyCollection>() != null);
            if (keys == null) keys = new KeyCollection(this);
            return keys;
        }
    }

    // Line 157
    public ValueCollection Values {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ValueCollection>() != null);
            if (values == null) values = new ValueCollection(this);
            return values;
        }
    }
```

Also if you look into the `KeyCollection` and `ValueCollection` Classes, you will notice, that there is no other implementation of the `Equals()` Method. As those classes don't derive from any other class, you may be sure that `dict.Keys.Equals(dict.Values)` will call the `object.Equals()` [Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2).

This call will obviously return false.